# Error while uploading large size image on aws s3 using cloudfront

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am getting following error while uploading large size image on s3 using cloudfront.

**Error:** SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I can upload same image without cloudfront on s3.

I can also upload small size image file(< 2 mb) using cloudfront.